# Django error templates in custom path

Tags: python, django

I have dir template with all templates, and I have dir errors, with all templates with errors 404.html.
I found the following old solution:

In urls.py my app I wrote

```
from django.conf.urls import (handler400, handler403, handler404, handler500)
handler404 = 'my_app.views.page_not_found'
```

And in view my app

```
from django.shortcuts import (render_to_response)
from django.template import RequestContext

def page_not_found(request):
    response = render_to_response(
    'errors/404.html',
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

But I use Django 1.11 and this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#handler404)

You should return HttpResponseNotFound which is the same as HttpResonse except for status code. It worked for me.

```
def bad_request(request):
    response = render_to_response(
        'errors/404.html'
    )

    return HttpResponseNotFound(response.content)
```